# Laravel/VueJs. How can I display button with different color based on column value passed in?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm looping through user table. And each user table has a button that toggle(update:Boolean type) user status on user table. And I want the button for each user to have red color when the status value for the user is 0 and green when the status is 1. Also I want the button to change the color(LIVE) based on the status value each time it clicked.

**component: ToggleStatus.vue**

```js
<template>
    <div>
      <button type="button" v-bind:class="buttonStatus" @click="goOnline">
          <span class="ion-ios-wifi" ></span>
      </button>
    </div>
</template>

    <script>
    export default {
      props: ['userId', 'onlinestat'],

      mounted() {
          console.log('Component mounted.')
      },

      data: function() {
        return {
          status: this.onlinestat,
          }
      },

      methods: {
        goOnline() {
          axios.post('/reservation/online/' + this.userId )
            .then(response => {
              this.status =! this.status;
              console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(errors => {
              if (errors.response.status == 401){
              window.location = '/login';
              }
            });
        }
      },

      computed: {
        buttonStatus() {
          return(this.status) ? 'btn btn-outline-danger text-danger' : 'btn btn-success ';
        }
      }

    }
   </script>
```

**Controller:**

```php
      $authUser = Auth::user()->business_id;
      $employee = User::where('business_id', $authUser)->get()->sortBy('name');

      return view('backend.reservation.index', compact('employee'));
```

**View/Blade**

```php
    <div class="container-fluid flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
        <div class="uikit-example">
          <div class="row">

            @foreach ($employee as $key => $emp)
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
              <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="media align-items-center">
                    <img src="{{ asset('Upload/Images/Media/Avatar/Thumb/'.$emp->image) }}" alt class="ui-w-60 rounded-circle">
                    <div class="media-body pt-2 ml-3">
                      <h5 class="mb-2">{{ $emp->name }}</h5>
                      <div class="text-muted small mb-2">{{ $emp->phone }}</div>
                      <div class="text-muted small mb-2">{{ $emp->email }}</div>
                      <div class="text-muted small mb-2"><span>ID:&nbsp;</span>{{ $emp->user_code }}</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="">
                      <toggleonline user-id="{{ $emp->id }}" onlinestat="{{ $emp->onlinestatus }}"></toggleonline>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-center py-3">
                  {{-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-success rounded-pill">+&nbsp; Go Online</a> --}}

                  &nbsp;
                  {{-- <a href="#" class="btn icon-btn btn-default md-btn-flat rounded-pill"><span class="ion ion-md-mail"></span></a> --}}
                  {{-- <div class="float-right"> --}}
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill mt-2">&nbsp; My Reservations</a>
                  {{-- </div> --}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          @endforeach
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

The result I'm getting is that the button does toggle but the toggle button of all the user come red after  on refresh page or when the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
buttonStatus() {
    return(this.status==0) ? 'btn btn-outline-danger text-danger' : 'btn btn-success ';
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the button come with the right color. It also toggles as expected when the value is 1. But when the value is 0 when you click n the button it will change the value from 0 to 1 on the background and NO color change, when you  click for the second time it will change the color to Green while the value changes to 0

Comment: for this you have to use proper boolean, instaed of 0,1 you have to use true and false. 
or else
 change `this.status =! this.status;` into
`if(this.status==0)
{
this.status=1;
}
else
{
this.status=0;
}`

Comment: Thank you so much. That's all I needed and works great!